# Why error 1400 Invalid window handle?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, win32com

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <Windows.h>

HWND WindowHandle;
HINSTANCE Instance;
const wchar_t WindowClassName[] = L"Temp Projcet";

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND _windowHandle, UINT _msg, WPARAM _param, LPARAM _param1) {
    switch (_msg) {
    case WM_PAINT: {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(WindowHandle, &ps);
        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
        EndPaint(WindowHandle, &ps);
    } break;
    case WM_CLOSE: {
        if (IDOK == MessageBoxW(WindowHandle, L"Quit?", L"My application", MB_OKCANCEL)) {
            DestroyWindow(WindowHandle);
        }
        return false;
    } break;
    case WM_DESTROY: {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    } break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProcW(WindowHandle, _msg, _param, _param1);
}

ATOM RegisterWindowClass(void) {
    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = Instance;
    wc.lpszClassName = WindowClassName;
    return RegisterClassW(&wc);
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE _instance, HINSTANCE _prevInstance, PWSTR _cmdLine, int _cmdShow) {
    Instance = _instance;
    RegisterWindowClass();

    WindowHandle = CreateWindowExW(
        0,
        WindowClassName,
        L"This a window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        Instance,
        NULL
    );

    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    // Why error 1400 Invalid window handle?

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, WindowHandle, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why does it return 1400 invalid handles when you create a window? Shouldn't it?There's no window handle in the create window function, okay? How could it be an invalid handle? I've been searching through the search engine for a long time, but still can't solve this problem?
Why does `CreateWindowExW()` return 1400?
Code in line 44.

Comment: Did you try running it through your debugger?

Comment: I can repro. `RegisterWindowClass` is successful but `CreateWindowExW` is indeed returning `NULL`.

Comment: It is just a bug, you need to use the _windowHandle parameter.  The global variable doesn't get a value until later, after CreateWindowEx returns.  Right now the handling of WM_NCCREATE gets screwed up, that's bad.

Answer (score 5):

You're using `WindowHandle` in the window procedure before it's been set to the return value of `CreateWindowEx`. Part of that `CreateWindowEx` call is calling the window procedure with `WM_NCCREATE` and `WM_CREATE`. Your window procedure calls `DefWindowProc` with a null handle at that point.

The simple solution here is to use the `_windowHandle` parameter instead of your `WindowHandle` global.

Also note that in order for your window to be visible, you'll need a call to `ShowWindow`. In addition, the quit message you post isn't specific to that window, so your `GetMessage` call will not retrieve it and the application won't end.

Comment: To write it explicitly, the 2nd argument for `GetMessage` should be `NULL` to handle window messages aswell as thread messages like `WM_QUIT`.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
DWORD err = GetLastError();
```

you haven't tested if there has actually been an error. You need to test the handle you get back from CreateWindowEx before you call GetLastError. Otherwise it will return some previous, unrelated error, or some random value.

Comment: WindowHandle is NULL

Answer (score 0):

Only call GetLastError after a failed CreateWindow (that is, if CreateWindow returns NULL).

the last error value is unspecified after the vast majority of successful windows API calls, you must check the return value before calling GetLastError.

Comment: CreateWindowExW() return NULL.